# Focusing fields in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have ten edit text item and validation for each field , when i click submit validation is processed , and if any invalidate field throw an alert , for example i have first name need to contain minimum 6 character , if validation fails i throw an alert .

what i need is to focus the invalidate field automatically after throwing alert for entering the right values.

If there is anyway to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the requestFocus() method on the edittext containing the invalid value